# Why 'seq' not work in a loop?

Tags: python

```
for i in range(10):
    print(i, sep = ',', end = '')
```

It should be `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`,but the truth is 
[image]
The `sep` does not work. Thanks!

Comment: You're only printing a single number at a time, there's nothing to separate as far as `print` is concerned.

Comment: You should do something like: `','.join([str(i) for i in range(10)])`. Others already mentioned why your version doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The optional `sep` argument is used to define the separator between comma separated argument values that are fed to the `objects` parameter of `print`. `objects` is a variable argument parameter, which means it can take any number of arguments (or an unpacked iterable).

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print):

> **print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)**
>
> Print
>   objects to the text stream file, separated by sep and followed by end.
>   sep, end and file, if present, must be given as keyword arguments.
>
> All non-keyword arguments are converted to strings like str() does and
>   written to the stream, separated by sep and followed by end. Both sep
>   and end must be strings; they can also be None, which means to use the
>   default values. If no objects are given, print() will just write end.

A better way of writing your code would be the following:

```
print(*range(10), sep=',', end='')
```

This uses the `*` operator to unpack the iterable and feed each of its elements in as arguments to the `print` function.

It is equivalent to:

```
print(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, sep=',', end='')
```

Answer (score 1):

In this loop, `i` is always a one digit integer and this can't be seperated.

It would be like this:

```
print("1", sep=',', end='')
print("2", sep=',', end='')
print("3", sep=',', end='')
...
```

Comment: `sep` mean seperator, and it only works if it can seperate something. So yes, it needs something it can iterate over. What do you expect when you tell `print` to seperate "1"?